# How can I draw a "cosinus- curve" without using math.()?

Tags: java

I am currently learning java. My professor has given me the task of representing the following pattern with squares. No imports or predefined classes may be used.

[Template pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HOf0.png)

At the moment i have programmed a pattern that is too square (see output picture). Unfortunately I can't get any further and don't know how to adapt my code.

```
public void zeichne_Sinus (Graphics g) {
        Zeichenblatt zeichenblatt = new Zeichenblatt(g);

        int repetitions = 5;

        for (int rep = 0; rep < repetitions; rep++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                Quadrat quad = new Quadrat();
                quad.setPositionX(i * 10 + rep * 100 + 10);
                quad.setPositionY(i * 10);
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    quad.setFarbe(Color.orange);
                } else {
                    quad.setFarbe(Color.green);
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                    Quadrat quad2 = new Quadrat();
                    quad2.setPositionX(j * 10 + rep * 100 + 60);
                    quad2.setPositionY((4 - j) * 10 + rep);
                    if (j % 2 == 0) {
                        quad2.setFarbe(Color.green);
                    } else {
                        quad2.setFarbe(Color.orange);
                    }

                    zeichenblatt.zeichne(quad, quad2);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UJ2U.png)

Can you help me?

Comment: There's lots of approximations out there.  e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bh%C4%81skara_I%27s_sine_approximation_formula

Comment: How "No imports or predefined classes may be used" ? What about `Graphics`, `Color`, and similar?

Comment: it's rather difficult to help with this, because the classes you're using are your professors own creation and we don't have access to them.

Comment: I think it all boils down to calculating square root without using `Math`. Did you perhaps have an exercise like that in your course?

Comment: You shouldn't need a double loop for this

Comment: **(1)** Your example indicates expected output is low resolution.  **(2)** Trigonometry function are periodic -- they repeat.  **So**, use those two facts:  Create an array of y positions. Use a table or calculator to find the cosine values you want. Instead of `quad.setPositionY(i * 10);` use something like  `quad.setPositionY(cosineValue[i%10]);`

Comment: More iterations and overlap the squares by half or more.